# How to perform this sort in MongoDB? (embedded sorting)

Tags: mongodb, database

```
chat = {
        messages: [ { body:"asdf", timestamp: 234256243 },
                 { body:"asdf", timestamp: 234256241 },
                 { body:"asdf", timestamp: 544256244 },
};
```

Suppose I had a collection of chat rooms. I want to find the rooms with the latest messages. How do I sort by the timestamp of messages?

```
chat.find().sort...by messages array timestamp descending.
```

It's an embedded sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not presently support for sorting embedded arrays in MongoDB. You'll need to do the sorting on the clientside with the programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed in a year. Mongodb now supports sorting by embedded arrays.

```
db.chat.find().sort({'messages.timestamp': -1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may want to add a 'latestMessage' attribute to the chat room (parent document) that is updated whenever a new message is posted.

Then you can just search and order by chat.latestMessage descending.

Bit of data duplication, but makes your life easier.